# Multi-Site Domain is not resolving Using Azure WAF

Tags: azure, paas

I am facing domain resolving issue in Sitecore Multi-Site Solution using Azure PaaS with Azure WAF setup, however, it's working fine if I add the custom domain on Content delivery(Web Apps) level.

**Scenario:**

We have to set up the multi-site solution, which needs to configure on Azure WAF level. The request is coming on WAF first then, CD (web apps) then the web.config( where the domain is resolving)

We have setup multi-domain on Azure WAF using this Microsoft blog:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-multiple-sites-portal

But the problem is – custom domain is not passing from Azure WAF to CD server(web apps) that’s the reason it’s not resolving the multi-site domain.

Below is the configuration we did on WAF level:

Configuring multi-site for Sitecore on Azure WAF
Steps involved and pre-requisites

1. Azure VNet setup
2. Azure WAF setup
3. Domain level changes
4. WAF - configuring multi-site

**Azure VNet setup:**

Azure VNet is required to privately deploy WAF and publicize with public FQDN or IP. Azure VNet can be safeguarded using azure DDoS, this will protect from any public or private vulnerabilities.

**WAF Setup**

Once the VNet is ready, the Azure application gateway can be launched in WAF mode (WAF/WAF2) to protect the Sitecore environment. Below are the elements of WAF to be created while consuming multi-site functionality at WAF.

- Backend pool
- HTTP Settings
- Front End IP configurations
- Listeners
- Rules
- Health Probes

Domain level changes

All the origin websites (domains/sub-domains) must be configured with the CNames pointing to Azure WAF FQDN.

**WAF Multi-site configuration**

Once the required domains are mapped with the Azure WAF FQDN, multiple sets of above-mentioned WAF elements should be created pointing to the respective website.

High-level[image] Flow diagram

It would be great if someone can help on this.

Answer (score 2):

What you might have missed (as it is not described in the blog link you referenced), you still need to add your custom hostnames to the Azure web app, even though the DNS record is pointing to the WAF.

To do this, you need to add a new DNS TXT "awverify" record for each of your custom domains, so that azure can validate it for your web app. See the first steps in this article:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-App-Service/Setting-up-Application-Gateway-with-WAF-with-an-App-Service-that/ba-p/392639

Once done, your web apps should immediately start resolving the custom domains for the requests that come through the WAF and are forwarded to your web app.